# Proton NMR of tert-amyl alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, nmr-spectroscopy

I just started learning about proton NMR.
According to [Molbase](https://www.molbase.com/en/hnmr_75-85-4-moldata-4350.html), the HNMR data for *tert*-amyl alcohol (2-methylbutan-1-ol) shows four kinds of protons at 0.9 ppm, 1.24 ppm, 1.44, and 3.65 ppm.

[image: Structure of tert-amyl alcohol]

However, it seems contradictory to what I learnt, since the protons on secondary carbon (1.44 ppm) are downfield to the protons on tertiary carbon (1.24 ppm), which confuses me, since I learnt that protons on tertiary carbons experience more de-shielding.

Is there something I have missed out in my thought process?

EDIT: Thanks to @orthocresol and @Buttonwood for pointing out my error. My revised question would then be:
Between the two types of protons on secondary carbons (1.24 and 1.44 ppm), why is it that the one at 1.44 ppm is more deshielded?

From what I understand, it is because carbon is more electronegative than hydrogen, therefore causing the deshielding effect, but at the same time from organic chemistry I learnt that alkyl groups are electron donating, which should cause shielding. Is there some misconception in my thinking?

Comment: (1) Since you're just starting, it's a great time for you to unlearn the terms "downfield" and "upfield". These are ancient terms which come from the era of [continuous-wave NMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance#Continuous-wave_(CW)_spectroscopy) and for some reason have not been erased from the literature yet. Stick to "deshielded" and "shielded"; they're much more easily understood. (2) In tert-amyl alcohol, I don't see any protons attached to *tertiary* carbons; only a secondary carbon, and two different types of methyl carbons. Could you clarify?

Comment: In addition to `@orthocresol`'s comment, your reference accounts _for four_ different types of protons.  Both in the visual representation as well as in the molecular structure-like one, there is the one shown for 3.65 ppm (which, depending on the experimental circumstances, either a) equally could be recorded at a different position, or b) could be invisible).

Comment: As a beginner to NMR, you should be aware of how important integration values in $\mathrm{^1H-NMR}$. If you knew and had them in your NMR, you could have easily identify these peaks.

Comment: @orthocresol ,Buttonwood Hi, I have updated the question, would it be possible for you to re-look at it

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Hi, yes I understand the utility of such integration values, but here I was wondering about the explanation for the chemical shifts of these peaks, hope this clears things up :)

Comment: You can just remove the older part of your question.

Comment: I recommend you add to your question a list with all peaks, their integral, and the group it belongs to. The description in your text is not correct, the molecule has only one secondary carbon atom.

Comment: There are only two kinds of protons: those are on primary carbon(s) and those on secondary carbon.

Comment: Let's be careful when we talk about "kinds," since that's not, to my knowledge, a standard term. There are 12 hydrogen atoms, and these are in chemically equivalent groups of 3, 2, 6, and 1. In principle these groups have different shifts, but in practice, the peaks may overlap or be so broad as to be difficult to see in a spectrum.

Comment: tert.-Amyl alcohol is 2-methylbutan-2-ol not 2-methylbutan-1-ol.